# Can I control the width of the API Management Portal container?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm struggling to find any documentation on customizing the API Management portal container layout. Can't seem to find them on their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-modify-content-layout). Ultimately I would like to make use of some of the wasted space on the sides and make the layout more modern like [Stripe's docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api#intro) with the 3 column layout.

Comment: pretty sure thats not possible

Comment: @4c74356b41 No way of overriding the css or injecting javascript to get the job done?

Comment: this is paas service. you dont really get to control it a lot. i just found this after a bit of googling. but you need the other portal, or the developer one? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-modify-content-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set all sorts of CSS for the developer portal.  Go to your developer portal and on the left near the top of the screen should be an icon that looks like this:

[image]

Hover over it and you should see a menu slide out.  Click styles and then search for "screen" in the search box.  Like below.

[image]

Set that to a fixed width or 100% and it should load the changes right away.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

[Here is a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-customize-styles) to the Microsoft Docs page on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to override the css for the container max-width by adding an html widget to the header.
[image]

[image]